# How to detect the current scene in Swift SpriteKit app

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my SpriteKit app I've 3 different scenes and I want to set a specific settings for each scene.
I mean I want set visible an AdBanner in MainPage and SomeInfoScene but not in GameScene. How can I do this?
This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

        let mainPage = SKScene(fileNamed: "MainPage")!
        mainPage.name = "MainPage"

        let someInfoPage = SKScene(fileNamed: "SomeInfoScene")!
        someInfoPage.name = "SomeInfoScene"

        let gameScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")!
        gameScene.name = "GameScene"

        view.presentScene(mainPage)

        if let currentScene = view.scene {

            if currentScene.name == mainPage.name {

                print("MainPage")
                adBannerView.isHidden = false
            }
            if currentScene.name == someInfoPage.name {

                print("SomeInfoScene")
                adBannerView.isHidden = false
            }
            if currentScene.name == gameScene.name {

                print("GameScene")
                adBannerView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Already made a comment in your other question.  The only page you will ever see is mainPage, the rest are useless.  Instead of making duplicate questions, you should spend more time on focusing on getting all the details of your question together, and ask 1 coherent question that thoroughly explains your problem.

Comment: They told me to resume the question, my question is: How can I set different settings for each scene?

Comment: Yes, because the question you asked in your last one had nothing to do with your problem, that is why I said you need to spend more time and focus on asking better questions. As for your problem, `viewDidLoad` only gets called once, so your `if let currentScene` needs to happen when a scene changes.  I have no idea how you are doing this, but where ever you are changing your scene, that is where you do your check.

Comment: Yes, I need a functions similar to update function in GameScene

Comment: no, you only change your scene on demand, you do not change your scene 1/60th of a second every second

Comment: Ok, and How can I do this? Can you help me ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157301/discussion-between-pietro-p-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: No, I do not have that kind of time to teach you how to use sprite kit.  I would recommend using tutorials to understand how the framework works

Comment: You are right, and which I can follow to understand how the framework works?

Comment: I have no idea, maybe raywenderlich.com.  i didn't need a tutorial on it so I have no idea what is best to recommend to somebody just starting out.